# Media Query To Center Image for Zurb Foundation 4

Tags: css, sass, media-queries, zurb-foundation

I'm sure that I'm doing something silly, but I can't seem to find it.

I'd like to take this page:
http://jekyll.tx0rx0.com

and have the little post preview images center when the text moves below them. I tried this media query:

```
@media (max-width: emCalc(600px))
{
    .smallcenter{
        display: block;
        text-align: center;
        float: center;
    }
}
```

The site uses the jekyll post generation system combined with git and the foundation 4 responsive framework
I want it to center the posts on anything from an ipad portrait size and downward, but it doesn't seem to be working. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your image is wrapped by an a tag, you could tell the a's parent to align the text centered.

I would move the *smallcenter* class to that outmost div (the .large-4 one) like that:

**HTML**

```
<div class="large-4 columns smallcenter">
  <a href="/postsurl"><img src="/assets/image.png" alt=" WHY NO WORK!"></a> 
</div>
```

**SASS**

```
@media (max-width: emCalc(600px)){
  .smallcenter {
    text-align: center;
    & > a {
      display: inline-block;
    }    
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you explain the line with the & and the >?It works, but I need to align the 600px value with Foundation's breakpoints. Do you know what they are? I found the breakpoint to be 80em. The display: inline-block; line causes text overlapping occasionally. Removing it fixed it

Comment: The & takes the wrapping selector and replaces the & with it. So you would end up with _.smallcenter > a_.
For the > sign have a look right here: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html